# Show that the intersection of an open set and the closure of any subset is a subset of the closure of the intersection of both subsets.

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be an open set and $B$ be a subset of a topological space $X$. Show that $A \cap cl(B) \subseteq cl(A \cap B)$.

I'm trying to show that for a point $x \in A \cap cl(B)$ that $x$ is in all closed sets containing $A \cap B$. However, I don't know how any of the theorems or definitions I've learned so far can carry me past this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint :

Assume $x\in A\cap cl(B)$.

If $x\in cl(B)$ then every open set containing $x$ should contain an element of $B$...

See that $x\in A$ and $A$ is open...

Answer (score 3):

For such $x \in A\cap cl(B)$ and for any open set $U$, notice that $a\in A$ and $A$ is open, then $x\in A\cap U$, so $(A\cap U) \cap B\not =\emptyset$ (since $x\in cl(B)$), i.e., $U\cap (A \cap B)\not=\emptyset$, which shows that $x\in cl(A\cap B)$.